# How to fix this code for Java to rotate an array for large arrays and large number of rotations?

Tags: java

The following code is for rotation of an integer array.
Takes user input for array size and then an input for the element upto which the array is to be rotated.

Doesn't work for large values of array size and the rotation element.

The following code works for 15 array elements and rotates by 11 numbers (I didn't try for higher numbers) but it fails for a 77 array element and for rotation by 69 numbers. 
It works with both sorted and unsorted array.
Why is it not working and how can I fix this?

```java
int dupRotate = D;

for(int j=N-1; j>=0; --j) {

    /* checks whether loop is to be stopped or not.
       bottom condition fails to stop the 1st iteration for 
       third loop run.
    */     
    if(dupRotate == 0) {
        break;
    }

    /* Exchanges elements here.
       for loop run1 - 
       arr = 1,2,3,4,5
       after j reaches index 1
       arr = 2,3,4,5,1.

       for loop run2 -
       arr = 2,3,4,5,1.
       after j reaches index 1
       arr = 3,4,5,1,2.
    */ 
    int temp = arr[0];
    arr[0] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;

    /* if j reaches 1
       decrements dupRotate and sets j = N 
       then for loop decrements j and starts loop again.
    */     

    if(j == 1 && dupRotate > 0) {
        dupRotate--;
        j = N;
    }

}
```

```
77 69
40 13 27 87 95 40 96 71 35 79 68 2 98 3 18 93 53 57 2 81 87 42 66 90 45 20 41 30 32 18 98 72 82 76 10 28 68 57 98 54 87 66 7 84 20 25 29 72 33 30 4 20 71 69 9 16 41 50 97 24 19 46 47 52 22 56 80 89 65 29 42 51 94 1 35 65 25
```

Its Correct output is:

```
29 42 51 94 1 35 65 25 40 13 27 87 95 40 96 71 35 79 68 2 98 3 18 93 53 57 2 81 87 42 66 90 45 20 41 30 32 18 98 72 82 76 10 28 68 57 98 54 87 66 7 84 20 25 29 72 33 30 4 20 71 69 9 16 41 50 97 24 19 46 47 52 22 56 80 89 65
```

And Your Code's output is:

```
45 20 41 30 32 18 98 72 82 76 10 28 68 57 98 54 87 66 7 84 20 25 29 72 33 30 4 20 71 69 9 16 41 50 97 24 19 46 47 52 22 56 80 89 65 29 42 51 94 1 35 65 69 40 13 27 87 95 40 96 71 35 79 68 2 98 3 18 93 53 57 2 81 87 42 66 90
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty hard to realise your problem. I have to add more description.

I think, if you use the correct algorithm of array rotation, then it does not depend on an array's length. This is one of the most efficient algorithm:

```
[1,2,3,4,5] -> k = 2 -> [4,5,1,2,3]
-----------------------------------
1. [1,2,3,4,5] -> [5,4,3,2,1] 
2. [5,4,3,2,1] -> [4,5,3,2,1]
3. [4,5,3,2,1] -> [4,5,1,2,3]
```

---

```
public static void rotate(int[] arr, int k) {
    if ((k %= arr.length) != 0) {
        k = k < 0 ? arr.length + k : k;
        swapSubArr(arr, 0, arr.length);               // 1.
        swapSubArr(arr, 0, arr.length - k);           // 2.
        swapSubArr(arr, arr.length - k, arr.length);  // 3.
    }
}

private static void swapSubArr(int[] arr, int from, int to) {
    for (int i = from, j = to - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
        swap(arr, i, j);
}

private static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move step by step

```
[1,2,3,4,5] -> k = 3 -> [4,5,1,2,3]
-----------------------------------
1. [1,2,3,4,5] -> [5,4,3,2,1] 
2. [5,4,3,2,1] -> [4,5,3,2,1]
3. [4,5,3,2,1] -> [4,5,1,2,3]
```

Code

```
static void rotate(int arr[], int k) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
        move(arr);
    }
}

static void move(int arr[]) {
    int i, n, tmp;
    n = arr.length;
    tmp = arr[0];
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
    }
    arr[i] = tmp;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int k = 3;
    // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    rotate(arr, k);
    // [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
}
```